# web.config <appSettings> <add key="orderToAddress">

Tags: asp.net, web-config

How many add keys can you have with "orderToAddress" value = "email@email.com" ?

I would like to have multiple e-mail addresses listed so an e-mail is sent to each "orderToAddress" and am not sure how many I can add.  Is the last one in the list the only one that will receive an e-mail?

Thanks,
TLF

Answer (score 0):

Key is a unique identifier. So you can't have multiple keys with same name (in this case "orderToAddress"). You need to have different names (e.g. orderToAddress1, orderToAddress2 etc) for each e-mail. Then you could have as many as you like.

But, my worry is why do you save these values in Web.config? You should consider to save these values in the DB or in a different config source.

Hope this helps!